# Script file file not being loaded through ScriptLink custom action - SharePoint app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-actions, caching, scriptlink

I am having trouble with script link custom actions. I am building a SharePoint app, and I successfully added a site-scope custom action pointing to a script file in the Style Library, as I want this particular script to be injected to all the pages of my SharePoint site.

While it works in certain situations, the script link injection breaks without apparent reason under certain conditions. For example, when I arrive on my root web, the script will be injected. But, if I go to a certain link within this web (for example Home or Site Contents), the file that is supposed to be injected will simply not be fetched from the Style Library and therefore never be injected, resulting in an uncaught ReferenceError when I try to call one of the script's function. The weirdest part is that a page refresh through Ctrl+F5 will fetch the script file without any problem, regardless of the page's ability to originally fetch the script file when first accessed. It will keep the script until it is accessed through a link again.

I've read up on Sharepoint caching, thinking it may be the cause of my problem, but the trouble is that these articles mostly talk about cache-induced errors when updating a file, while I am only trying to access it.

One thing to note is that, due to limitations, I am adding the script link custom action through code. Here's an example of what this kind of call currently looks like in my app:

context.Load(context.Site.UserCustomActions);
context.ExecuteQuery();

```
customAction.Name = "MyScriptLink";
customAction.Location = "ScriptLink";
customAction.Sequence = 100;
customAction.ScriptSrc = "~SiteCollection/Style Library/MySite/MyScript.js";

customAction.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Also, I know the custom action itself works, since changing the code I just showed by adding instructions in a *ScriptBlock* property instead of relying on fetching a file through *ScriptSrc* works like a charm; the code is executed in every page.

So, what's going on here ? Why is my script no injected on certain pages ? Why does a refresh on these exact same pages manage to fetch the file without any problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it ! Three words: Minimum Download Strategy. Disable it, it messes with you page redirect behavior within a SharePoint site (either through code or through site settings)